# How can I identify tab (or get its id) in Safari App Extension?

Tags: safari-app-extension

I am developing an Safari App Extension and I would like to identify opened tab. I found no id or no way to do that.

Chrome has an awesome API for doing that: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs. How can I do it with Safari App Extension (in Swift)?

Safari tab API is very poor and does not contain ID (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafaritab)

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The API is not easy to use. However, there is a way to get the ID. The `SFSafariPage` itself.

The `SFSafariPage` adopt `NSSecureCoding`. You can use `savedPage.isEqual(newPage)` to compare if the same page you get from `getActiveTab` or something. The page is a pointer or proxy. But the content is unique.

P.S 
You should very careful about the `SFSafariExtensionHandler`. The handler is always a new object. Use the singleton model save page index could make sure data won't lost.

Answer (score 0):

A little more detail would be helpful. What do you mean 'ID'? What do you actually want to do? 
You can get access to tabs in your extension handler using [SFSafariApplication API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariapplication). I've not tested it myself, but it may look something like this:

```
SFSafariApplication.getActiveWindow { (window) in
    window?.getActiveTab { (tab) in
       ...do something with the tab...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello,
By getting active tab, i have no idea which tab it is. You can look at Chrome documentation (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs), i can identify a tab by an id.

If i open a tab, i can reach it anymore from background, i can't said "it is the same tab that i opened".

For my example, i want to open two tab and when i receive request, be able to know "It is tab number one, it it tab number two"

Comment: Ah I see. I wonder if you might be able to use some state in javascript? For example, when you open a new tab, send a message that will set some identifier that is managed by your extension.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate a bit what you are trying to achieve?

I suppose, at the worst case, you can inject a script in every page, where you will generate a random ID, send it to the host app, which will store them all into UserDefaults. Then later, when you need to retrieve a tab, you'd iterate over all tabs and establish some communication with the one you are targeting with `dispatchMessageToScript`.

<s>`SFSafariTab` inherits `hashValue` from `NSObject`. This could allow you to identify your tab.</s>

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your suggestion but it does not work.
Indeed, SFSafariTab is not a class that represent the tab object but it is a *proxy* for this tab. ("A proxy for a tab in a Safari window." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafaritab).

Hash or object memory reference change for each call. :/

Comment: Sorry for my initial answer, you are absolutely right. I edited my answer.

Comment: Haha I just realized quin basically recommended the same thing :)

Comment: According to your new description, i image this example:
You have two tabs (google.com and ebay.com). You generate random ID (1 and 2) and you store in the UserDefaults like you suggested. If i close ebay tab, how you know it ? :)